# double::TryParse Issue

Tags: c++-cli

I am having the strangest problem...When I convert from a textbox->text into a double , I get the number .99999999991 if a zero was in the text box. Why is this? Here is my example code:

```
double theNumber = 0;

if( !double::TryParse( mTheText->Text, theNumber ) )
{
    return false;
}
```

Notice that double is set to zero at the start and is later set to .99999999991 after the tryparse is called. I use this exact code elsewhere and it works fine. What is happening here? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

This this issue is now resolved, I recommend that you answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing `theNumber` to `0.0` instead of `0`?

Comment: Resolved. There is no parser issue. Someone had mixed the names of the text boxes up.

Comment: I was unable to comment on your post so I had to post my response as an answer. `I use this exact code elsewhere and it works fine.` the exact code, including getting the string to be parsed from a textbox?

EDIT: great!